# Change Tomcat logging location to custom location with hostname as a directory

Tags: java, tomcat

Change Tomcat logging location to custom location with hostname as directory
example:
if the server hostname is "frontend"
tomcat logs directory should be: frontend/logs/

Which property must be defined in tomcat logging.properties ?? to fetch hostname ?

**Edit** (from deleted *"answer"*): `frontend` is the name of the machine running Tomcat. The OS is Ubuntu-18.04.

Comment: Do you want to use the name of the machine running Tomcat or the name of the `<Host>` element containing the application? What OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The [`ClassLoaderLogManager`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/juli/ClassLoaderLogManager.html), which reads the logging configuration in Tomcat has a limited placeholder `${...}` replacement capability. It can replace:

- Java system properties,
- the three virtual properties `classloader.webappName` (context name of the application), `classloader.hostName` (name of the `<Host>` element), `classloader.serviceName` (name of the `<Service>` element).

Since **no** Java property contains the hostname, the easiest way to use it in `logging.properties` is to hardcode it.

Otherwise you need to create a Java system property containing the hostname (e.g. `hostname`) by passing a `-Dhostname=...` JVM option to Tomcat. On Debianoids you can add the switch in `/etc/default/tomcat9`:

```sh
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -Dhostname=$HOSTNAME"
```

Then you can use the system property defined above in `logging.properties`, e.g. you can replace:

```
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
```

with

```
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/${hostname}/logs
```